# Find how many numbers two numbers have in common

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I'm trying to make a program that tells the user how many numbers both inputted numbers have in common

FOR EXAMPLE:
if inputted n1 = 765 and n2 = 572 then the program returns 2 because both numbers have 7 and 5 in them.

I made this but it isn't working:

````
    p = []
i = []
counter = [0] * 10
answer = 0

def conv(a):
  p = [list(map(int, a))]
  return p

def fed(a):
  i = [list(map(int, a))]
  return i

while True:
 n = str(input("Enter the first number :"))
 conv(n)
 v = str(input("Enter the second number: " ))
 fed(v)
 counter = [0] * 10
 answer = 0
 for x in p:
   counter[x] += 1
   for x in i:
      if counter[x] > 0:
        counter[x] -= 1
        answer += 1
  print(answer)```
````

Comment: There is a number of issues with this code.

Comment: What do you mean *it isn't working*? What is the error message? What are the expected and observed outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [sets](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) instead, like so:

```
while True:
    nums = []
    nums.append(input('Enter first number: '))
    nums.append(input('Enter second number: '))
    digits = [set(x) for x in nums]
    num_comm = len(digits[0] & digits[1])
    print(num_comm)
```

Comment: aaah I see! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to make your program much shorter, you can use [sets](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_set.asp) and find the [intersection](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_intersection.asp) of the two numbers:

```
while True:
  n1 = str(input("Enter the first number: "))
  n2 = str(input("Enter the second number: "))
  def number(n1, n2):
    return len(set(n1)).intersection(n2))
  print(number(n1, n2))
```

Output:

```
  #Enter the first number: 765
  #Enter the second number: 572
  >>> 2
```

Comment: @TimurShtatland Edited. Thanks!